# Python input to use as function argument

Tags: python, function, keras, input, user-input

I have a class for which i would like to control the input-argument from a terminal.

The class relates to machine learning, and is called keras.layers.LSTM(). It has an input argument called bias_regularizer, which takes as input a regulizer object l1 or l2, that i import from a keras library. I would like to set it like this:

```
keras.layers.LSTM(bias_regularizer = l1(0.01)) #Runs fine when hardcoded
```

But when i try to define it as an x, and give it as an input it fails, since input converts the userinput to a string.

```
x = input('input parameter: ') #I input l1(0.01) from the terminal
keras.layers.LSTM(bias_regularizer=x) #Fails cause x is a string
```

This method works fine for other arguments for the keras.layers.LSTM class, where the input is either a string or an int (i use int(input()) to convert it), but it fails here.

Is there a way for me to neglect the datatype of the input, and pass my input to the function as if i wrote it myself? Hope the question makes sense.
Link to the LSTM class can be found here: https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/

Comment: Technically speaking, yes, there is a way, but it's almost never the right answer.  You can say `bias_regularizer=eval(x)` and have `x` evaluated as Python code.  It is strongly discouraged because it is so dangerous.  A user can type `os.system("rm -rf ~/*")` and screw things up.  It would be better to type `1` or `2` and have `l1(0.01) if inp == '1' else l2(0.01)`.

Comment: Right, so i can only make a sort of menu of possible inputs, and sadly not have full control of this particular input from the terminal.

Comment: That is the safe way, yes.